# Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\S]+

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to do a lambda on aws to list the users of my cognito user pool. This is my code in nodejs:

```
  const queryStringParameters = event.queryStringParameters;
  var paginationToken = '';
  if ( queryStringParameters && queryStringParameters.paginationToken ) {
    paginationToken = queryStringParameters.paginationToken;
  }
  var limit = '10';
  if ( queryStringParameters && queryStringParameters.limit ) {
    limit = queryStringParameters.limit;
  }

  var params = {};
  if ( paginationToken != '' ) {
    params = {
      UserPoolId: userPoolId, /* required */
      //Filter: 'STRING_VALUE',
      Limit: limit,
      PaginationToken: paginationToken
    };
  } else {
    params = {
      UserPoolId: userPoolId, /* required */
      //Filter: 'STRING_VALUE',
      Limit: limit,
      PaginationToken: paginationToken
    };
  }

  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      response.code = "ERROR"
      response.message = "Han ocurrido errores"
      response.result = err
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(response)
      })
    }
    response.code = "OK"
    response.message = ""
    response.result = data
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(response)
    });
  });
```

I am testing this lambda on postman with the paginationToken that was returned in other call. This error is returned.

```
{
    "code": "ERROR",
    "message": "Han ocurrido errores",
    "result": {
        "message": "1 validation error detected: Value 'CAISlAIIARLtAQgDEugBAEZixxOnN/v8zMwVa6CHVhw64qYzvU6Iyb5RkRwGsNS eyJAbiI6IlBhZ2luYXRpb25Db250aW51YXRpb25EVE8iLCJuZXh0S2V5IjoiQUFBQUFBQUFCYnYwQVFFQnU0V1pTVlZ1U0FDU1JZODJ4Mk9lL2RxVFRXbVZ3a3RScGVwQXNQT2JTWnBsYm1ZN01ETm1OREk0WVRNdFlqRmxZeTAwT0RZeExUaGpObVF0WkRZeU1ETXlZamd5T1RNek93PT0iLCJwcmV2aW91c1JlcXVlc3RUaW1lIjoxNTY1ODQ1MzU5NTU3fRog0tB4u0ATjZVYBFSGxE llc8AXn2 tEFfFFohzHQmeyY=' at 'paginationToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\S]+",
        "code": "InvalidParameterException",
        "time": "2019-08-18T17:37:37.581Z",
        "requestId": "acd206e0-006a-4208-b298-78d8cd8d770e",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 12.077823285760259
    }
}
```

I am trying this:

**https://{endpoint}/dev/users/list?limit=10&paginationToken=CAISlAIIARLtAQgDEugBAEZixxOnN/v8zMwVa6CHVhw64qYzvU6Iyb5RkRwGsNS+eyJAbiI6IlBhZ2luYXRpb25Db250aW51YXRpb25EVE8iLCJuZXh0S2V5IjoiQUFBQUFBQUFCYnYwQVFFQnU0V1pTVlZ1U0FDU1JZODJ4Mk9lL2RxVFRXbVZ3a3RScGVwQXNQT2JTWnBsYm1ZN01ETm1OREk0WVRNdFlqRmxZeTAwT0RZeExUaGpObVF0WkRZeU1ETXlZamd5T1RNek93PT0iLCJwcmV2aW91c1JlcXVlc3RUaW1lIjoxNTY1ODQ1MzU5NTU3fRog0tB4u0ATjZVYBFSGxE+llc8AXn2+tEFfFFohzHQmeyY=**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the plus (+) symbol in the PaginationToken. The endpoint receives the token with a whitespace instead of the plus symbol so a simple replace will fix it.

```
  PaginationToken = PaginationToken.replace(/\ /g,'+')
```